# How to randomly select from a list of 47 names that are entered from a data file?

Tags: matlab

I have managed to input a number data file into a matrix but have been unable to do so for any data that is not a number.

I have a list of 47 names and supposed to generate a random name from the list. I have tried to use the function **textscan** but was not going anywhere. Also how do I generate a random name from the list? All I have been able to do was generate a random number between 1 to 47.

---

Appreciate the replies. I should have said I need it in MATLAB sorry.

Here is a sample list of data in my data file

```
name01
name02
name03
```

and the code to read it:

```
fid = fopen('names.dat','rt');
headerChars = fgetl(fid);
data = fscanf(fid,'%f,%f,%f,%f',[4 47]).';
fclose(fid);
```

The above is what I have to read the data file into a matrix but it is only reading the first line. (Yes it was modified from a previous post here on this forums :/)

Comment: Could you post a sample of the contents of the data file, so we can see what format it is in?

Comment: please note that the data file contents were given one per line (didn't appear so because of SO formatting). Sorry if my edit breaks any solution. If this not what the OP intended, I will rollback..

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: As per the helpful comments from mtrw, and the fixed formatting of the sample data file, I've updated my answer with more detail.*

With a single name (i.e. "Bob", "Bob Smith", or "Smith, Bob") on each line of the file, you can use the function [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) by specifying `'%s'` as the format argument (to denote reading a string) and the newline character `'\n'` as the `'Delimiter'` (the character that separates the strings in the file):

```
fid = fopen('namefile.txt','r');
names = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);
```

Then it's a matter of randomly picking one of the names. You can use the function [RANDI](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html) to generate a random integer in the range from 1 to the number of names read from the file (found using the [NUMEL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/numel.html) function):

```
names = names{1};  %# Get the contents from the cell returned by TEXTSCAN
selectedName = names{randi(numel(names))};
```

Comment: @gnovice - man, you type fast.
@New2Matlab - The only thing I'd add to gnovice's answer is if your file looks like:
  Alice Jones Bob Smith Charlie Brown
then change the textscan line to
  names = textscan(fid, '%s %s', 'CollectOutput', 1);
and split the selection into:
  idx = randi(length(names));
  selectedName = {names{idx,:}};

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind me asking gnovice, may I know what Delimiter does?

Comment: @New2Matlab - the 'Delimiter' option allows you to specify the characters that appear between fields. For instance, if your file has each name on a separate line, you can use 'Delimiter', '\n'.  Strictly speaking, you don't need the delimiter option gnovice used because whitespace is the default delimiter.  See http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're halfway home. Take that random number and use it as an index for the list.

For example, if you randomly generate the number 23 then fetch the 23rd entry in the list which gives you a random name draw.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RANDOMBETWEEN function to get a random number within your range.  Use INDEX to get the actual cell value.  For instance:

```
=INDEX(A1:A47, RANDBETWEEN(1, 47))
```

The above will work for your specific case of 47 names, assuming they're in column A.  In general, you'd want something like:

```
=INDEX(MyNames, RANDBETWEEN(ROW(MyNames), ROW(MyNames) + ROWS(MyNames) - 1))
```

This assumes you've named your range of cells "MyNames" (for example, by selecting all the cells in your range and setting a name in the naming box).  The above formula works by using the ROW function to return the top row of the MyNames array and the ROWS function to get the total rows in MyNames.

Comment: I'm guessing that's in Excel? I think the OP wanted a MATLAB solution.

Comment: Ya... sorry I should have specified about the matlab part. Thanks for the reply